# Isn't Facebook Apptoken Oauth2 client credential unsecure since it sends login credentials request in GET URL?

Tags: oauth2, facebook

[Facebook Apptoken](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens) uses OAuth2 client credential code. But the `client_id` and `client_secret` are sent to the servier via HTTP GET method. Isn't this unsecure ?

For instance, any node that has logging enabled between the client and the Facebook server will log the GET URL. Thus exposing login credentials in their logs in clear text.

I think it's unsecured. Or am I missing something ?
Are there other more secure ways to implement client credential that you know ?

[image: Screenshot from Facebook Apptoken website]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, that sending any credentials as GET parameter isn't best practice. [OWASP ASVS](https://github.com/OWASP/ASVS/blob/v4.0.1/4.0/OWASP%20Application%20Security%20Verification%20Standard%204.0-en.pdf) (currently version 4.0.1) states this explicitly in requirement 3.1.1:

```
Verify the application never reveals session tokens in URL parameters or error messages.
```

In addition, [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.2) gives an actual example for the client credentials grant, where the token is sent as POST request with an Authorization header.

While using GET parameters for tokens is not best practice for several good reasons, the risk is not that severe, as you are using TLS and communication (including URL parameter) is encrypted between the client and the server. In addition, we are talking about back-end to server communication, where the URL isn't even exposed in the client, so it isn't stored in a browser history and the URL isn't directly exposed to a potentially irresponsible user.

Nevertheless, if you have the option, you should go with the token as POST parameter or as HEADER value.

Comment: Your answer made perfect sense to me. I understand better why they say OAuth2 security rely mostly on using SSL. Also, one should hope the backend knows how to remain confidential

Comment: Just beware of how logging is configured on the server that perform the calls and who has access to them

Comment: @FelipePereira Hmmm. I don't know if web servers can log HTTPS GET URL. Do you know an instance of webserver that does so ?

Comment: @tommy is common to have server logs to see, among other things, if errors happen, and in those cases it is usual to log the request associated to the error (imagine a call to the auth api timesout). In these cases the log could contain sensitive information